# Get the order item name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, orders

So I have a variable, if I `var_dump` that variable I get a big array. I'm trying to get the following:

```
["name"]=> string(26) "Online marketing Duitsland"
```

The entire array result looks like this:

```
array(1) { 
  [33]=> object(WC_Order_Item_Product)#9730 (11) { 
    ["extra_data":protected]=> array(9) { 
      ["product_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["variation_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["quantity"]=> int(1) 
      ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" 
      ["subtotal"]=> int(0) 
      ["subtotal_tax"]=> int(0) 
      ["total"]=> int(0) 
      ["total_tax"]=> int(0) 
      ["taxes"]=> array(2) { 
        ["subtotal"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["total"]=> array(0) { } 
      } 
    } 
    ["data":protected]=> array(11) { 
      ["order_id"]=> int(12291) 
      ["name"]=> string(26) "Online marketing Duitsland" 
      ["product_id"]=> int(11927) 
      ["variation_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["quantity"]=> int(1) 
      ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" 
      ["subtotal"]=> string(4) "3700" 
      ["subtotal_tax"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["total"]=> string(4) "3700" 
      ["total_tax"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["taxes"]=> array(2) { 
        ["total"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["subtotal"]=> array(0) { } 
      } 
    } 
    ["cache_group":protected]=> string(11) "order-items" 
    ["meta_type":protected]=> string(10) "order_item" 
    ["object_type":protected]=> string(10) "order_item" 
    ["id":protected]=> int(33) 
    ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["object_read":protected]=> bool(true) 
    ["default_data":protected]=> array(11) { 
      ["order_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["name"]=> string(0) "" 
      ["product_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["variation_id"]=> int(0) 
      ["quantity"]=> int(1) 
      ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" 
      ["subtotal"]=> int(0) 
      ["subtotal_tax"]=> int(0) 
      ["total"]=> int(0) 
      ["total_tax"]=> int(0) 
      ["taxes"]=> array(2) { 
        ["subtotal"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["total"]=> array(0) { } 
      } 
    } 
    ["data_store":protected]=> object(WC_Data_Store)#9723 (4) { 
      ["instance":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> object(WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store)#9722 (3) { 
        ["internal_meta_keys":protected]=> array(20) { 
          [0]=> string(9) "_order_id" 
          [1]=> string(5) "_name" 
          [2]=> string(11) "_product_id" 
          [3]=> string(13) "_variation_id" 
          [4]=> string(9) "_quantity" 
          [5]=> string(10) "_tax_class" 
          [6]=> string(9) "_subtotal" 
          [7]=> string(13) "_subtotal_tax" 
          [8]=> string(6) "_total" 
          [9]=> string(10) "_total_tax" 
          [10]=> string(6) "_taxes" 
          [11]=> string(11) "_product_id" 
          [12]=> string(13) "_variation_id" 
          [13]=> string(4) "_qty" 
          [14]=> string(10) "_tax_class" 
          [15]=> string(14) "_line_subtotal" 
          [16]=> string(18) "_line_subtotal_tax" 
          [17]=> string(11) "_line_total" 
          [18]=> string(9) "_line_tax" 
          [19]=> string(14) "_line_tax_data" 
        } 
        ["meta_type":protected]=> string(10) "order_item" 
        ["object_id_field_for_meta":protected]=> string(13) "order_item_id" 
      } 
      ["stores":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> array(20) { 
        ["coupon"]=> string(24) "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["customer"]=> string(22) "WC_Customer_Data_Store" 
        ["customer-download"]=> string(31) "WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store" 
        ["customer-download-log"]=> string(35) "WC_Customer_Download_Log_Data_Store" 
        ["customer-session"]=> string(30) "WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session" 
        ["order"]=> string(23) "WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["order-refund"]=> string(30) "WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["order-item"]=> string(24) "WC_Order_Item_Data_Store" 
        ["order-item-coupon"]=> string(31) "WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store" 
        ["order-item-fee"]=> string(28) "WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store" 
        ["order-item-product"]=> string(32) "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" 
        ["order-item-shipping"]=> string(33) "WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store" 
        ["order-item-tax"]=> string(28) "WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store" 
        ["payment-token"]=> string(27) "WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store" 
        ["product"]=> string(25) "WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["product-grouped"]=> string(33) "WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["product-variable"]=> string(34) "WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["product-variation"]=> string(35) "WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT" 
        ["shipping-zone"]=> string(27) "WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store" 
        ["webhook"]=> string(21) "WC_Webhook_Data_Store" 
      } 
      ["current_class_name":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> string(32) "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" 
      ["object_type":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> string(18) "order-item-product" 
    } 
    ["meta_data":protected]=> array(0) { } 
  } 
}
```

How do I get that specific part?

Comment: see this solution Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3

Comment: First, you need to use a **foreach loop** and after inside it you can use `get_name()` method like: `foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){ echo $item->get_name(); }` … Or if you have just one order item: `$items = $order->get_items(); $item = reset( $items ); echo $item->get_name();`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you very much this helped me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use get_name() method

```
$var[33]->get_name();
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html#_get_name

Comment: var_dump($order->get_items()[33]->get_name()) I tried this, it worked before my break..when i came back  i had an error. im so confused

Comment: It’s probably because it’s not 33 anymore

Comment: Where ate you taking this variable from?

Comment: I ended up doing it the way of @LoicTheAztec. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Either try:-

```
echo $arr[33]->data->name;
```

Or try:-

```
 $arr = (Array)$arr;//cast the object as an Array
 echo $arr[33]["\0*\0" . 'data']['name'];
```

For more support and understanding:- [Access Private and Protected Properties of Objects in PHP](https://blag.kazeno.net/development/access-private-protected-properties)

Comment: It will not work, data is protected property